# Odoo validate invoice bug?

Tags: validation, import, odoo-8, invoice

I can't seem to validate an invoice which I imported from a csv-file.
A invoice which I create in Odoo itself can be validated.

I checked the columns of both the imported and created entries with pgadmin, and they are both identical. When I export the invoices and then back import them, I'm still only able to validate the one I've created.

So I suppose there is some link with another table in Odoo? But I can't seem to find it.

Any help pls.

Comment: Are you importing it with state draft?, you may be breaking the workflow

Comment: yes I do, how do you mean breaking the workflow?

Comment: Try not importing the state. With workflow i mean Settings > workflows > workflows > account.invoice.basic. The invoices are treated with workflows, if you import files you break it if you dont import them right. Try deleting the column state from csv and try again. Else, if you are not including that column, do it with value 'draft'.

Comment: When I don't import a state the invoice doesn't have a state which means I can't do anything with it, since it's not in the workflow. When I enter 'draft' in the column in my csv-file I get the problem I posted (this is wat I did initially)

Comment: But did you try without that state column?

Comment: Yes, then it has no state and I can't confirm, cancel or do anything with it